# Lock Screen + Password lock Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a security enhancement android application. There is a need to lock the android phone, hence using Device admin and it works fine.

But, when setting a password, i'm in need of using Intents or i'm navigated to in-built UI screens to enter password.

`Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
                startActivity(intent);`

Is there any way to set password without using default screens / without UI ?

Kindly help me..

Comment: Did U Completed this Security Enhancement App.
I need the same thing to be Implemented but not getting What to do ?
Specially Locking the Screen with Password...
Please Help Me in This..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey Siba plz help me in this !!!

Comment: @NayanRath Answer by Tom Janssens works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DevicePolicyManager DPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
String pw = "abcd123";
DPM.resetPassword(pw, DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

Not sure this is what you need but it's how I set passwords for the user.

Answer (score 1):

No - and the reason for this is that from Google's perspective (your requirements may vary, but you're in the minority) the user should always have a chance to know the password for their device.  Allowing an application, even as a Device Policy Manager, to change the password without user input could lock a user out of the device they might need to function without them understanding why, which is a very poor UX design.  You can reset the user's password, or, as you've already noted, launch the screens to help them change their password but that's the best you're going to be able to manage without a custom build of the OS.

Comment: This is a scenario for phone lost or stolen case. i hope it is a valid  usecase.

Comment: @siva Justifying your use case does not change Google's policies. You may not modify security-related components of the OS without the user having control over every step.

Comment: @siva Google has other means for a stolen phone.  The assumption is that devices that have been stolen are pretty defenseless - nothing stops a would be hacker with physical access to the device.  The best you can do in that case is to wipe the data, which there is an API call for - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData(int)

Comment: @Eric Remote lock isnt feature where we will create a random pin. It is the same password reset where we can get the pin from user/owner via a web interface and lock the phone with a user-defined password.I hope i adhere to the policies of Google.

Comment: @JRaymond Something is always better than nothing. This is my perception.

Comment: @siva If the proper policies are in effect before the device is stolen, the thief can get none of your data anyway.  If your assumption is that somehow the thief knows your device password, this seems highly unlikely.  If the assumption is that the device is the valuable part, you're out of luck - all the thief has to do is to reboot into recovery and wipe the device; no matter what protections you have in place.  Most businesses assume that the data is what is valuable - for which android has the faculties available to have the device encrypted on lock and erased on demand.